# Импорт из excel в датафрейм и обратно в excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel

Cчитываю из экселя строки, которые определены как строчный тип данных, но пандас почему-то их превращает то в numpy.int64, то numpy.float64. Из-за этого при переносе в  эксель идет округление, что мне не нужно. Вопрос: почему пандас превращает строку в число и как этого не допустить? При переносе с sql таких трудностей нет.

```
import pandas as pd
xlsx = pd.read_excel("input2.xlsx")
xlsx.index += 1
with pd.ExcelWriter("output_ex.xlsx") as writer:
   xlsx.to_excel(writer)
print(xlsx.iloc[0]["A6"])
print(type(xlsx.iloc[0]["A6"]))
```

ссылка на эксель: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_3lsWqHW-pe9V8BFq6eqXXkRYaP73CQ/edit#gid=2011771124

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [параметром `dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel("input2.xlsx", dtype={"A6": str})
```

результат:

```
In [84]: df["A6"]
Out[84]:
0    5853400884000091
1    5847040869000192
2    5855540881000038
3    5855640873000093
4    5897899797000395
Name: A6, dtype: object   # <--- NOTE !
```

Из документации:

> **dtype** Type name or dict of column -> type, default None Data type for data or columns. E.g. `{‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32}` Use
> object to preserve data as stored in Excel and not interpret dtype. If
> converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype
> conversion.

---

Проверка кода на Pandas 1.4.1, OpenPyxl 3.0.9:

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_excel("input2.xlsx", dtype={"A6": "str"})

In [2]: df["A6"]
Out[2]:
0    5853400884000091
1    5847040869000192
2    5855540881000038
3    5855640873000093
4    5897899797000395
Name: A6, dtype: object

In [3]: pd.__version__
Out[3]: '1.4.1'
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot interpret '{'A6', <class 'str'>}' as a data type

Comment: странно, у меня этот код отработал без ошибок на вашем файле. Попробуйте `dtype={"A6", "str"}`

Comment: Cannot interpret '{'A6', 'str'}' as a data type. Не знаете как правильно указать путь на колабе? Хочу на нем опробовать

Comment: какая у вас версия Pandas? Вы пробовали запустить `pd.read_excel("input2.xlsx", dtype={"A6", "str"})` __с вашим файлом__ по ссылке?

Comment: Да, все верно, версия 1.4.1

Comment: @АндрейКовров, специально установил версию 1.4.1 и перепроверил - все работает (см. обновленный ответ)

Comment: я уверен, что на моей стороне ошибка, но не могу понять в чем

Comment: пробовали запустить `df = pd.read_excel("input2.xlsx", dtype={"A6": "str"})` __ничего не меняя в этой строке__ (кроме путей к Excel файлу)?

Comment: Вы написали выше: df = pd.read_excel("input2.xlsx", dtype={"A6", str}), а в тестировании: df = pd.read_excel("input2.xlsx", dtype={"A6": "str"}), разницу видите? двоеточие, а не запятая, потому не запускалось, я и сам невнимательный, этот момент просмотрел, все работает, спасибо!)